# php function file_put_contents with resouce doesn't work

Tags: php, php-5.5

After that I use file_put_contents with resouce variable, this variable appear blank and I cannot reuse it.

Es.:

```
$stream = $entity->getData();
var_dump(stream_get_contents($stream));//this return string
file_put_contents("test.txt",$stream);
var_dump(stream_get_contents($stream)); //this return empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

As written in the documentation :

> If data is a stream resource, the remaining buffer of that stream will
>   be copied to the specified file. This is similar with using
>   stream_copy_to_stream().

Which means that it will push the stream pointer to the end of the file.

You can reset your pointer position using `rewind`. (Or keep track of your stream position if you don't want to fully rewind)

i.e :

```
rewind($stream);
```